# XSLT 2.0 dynamic table count

Tags: xml, function, xslt

I'm having trouble producing the right output from an XML transformation into a html table.

Input XML:

```
    <Report>
      <Report>
        <objective objective="Y1">
          <function function="X1" />
          <function function="X3" />
          <function function="X4" />
          <function function="X2" />
          <function function="X6" />
        </objective>

        <objective objective="Y2" />

        <objective objective="Y3" />

        <objective objective="Y4">
          <function function="X5" />
          <function function="X3" />
        </objective>
        <objective objective="Y5">
          <function function="X2" />
          <function function="X1" />
          <function function="X4" />
        </objective>
      </Report>
    </Report>
```

Wanted Output:

[image]

This is what I have so far; My XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">



<xsl:template match ="Report/Report" >
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

            <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Objective\Function</th>

                    <xsl:for-each-group select="objective/function" group-by="@function">
                    <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>

                    <th><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></th>
                     </xsl:for-each-group>
                </tr>
                    <xsl:variable name="allData" select="objective"/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="objective">
                <tr>

                        <td><xsl:value-of select="@objective"></xsl:value-of></td>                          

                        <xsl:for-each-group select="$allData" group-by="function/@function">

                             <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>

                                  <td><xsl:value-of select="count(current-grouping-key())"/></td>

                        </xsl:for-each-group>

                </tr>

                </xsl:for-each>

            </tbody>
            </table>

    </body>
    </html>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I think I'm rather close, I think something must be done with the count function:

[image]

Basically what I want is:

If @function which belongs to the function node is related to the parent's attribute @objective then count 1 (depending on the occurrences), otherwise 0. I thank you in advance, have been struggling for the past few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your current **xsl:for-each** loop for **objective** elements, you can define a variable to hold a reference to the current element

```
<xsl:for-each select="objective">
   <xsl:variable name="current" select="." />
```

Then, to within the second **xsl:for-each-group** where you are iterating over the **function** elements, you can simply count the number of **function** elements within the current **objective** (held in the variable) that match the grouping key (so will either be 0 or 1)

```
<xsl:value-of select="count($current[function/@function=current-grouping-key()])"/>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
      exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn">
<xsl:template match ="Report/Report" >
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Objective\Function</th>
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="objective/function" group-by="@function">
                    <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                    <th><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></th>
                     </xsl:for-each-group>
                </tr>
                    <xsl:variable name="allData" select="objective"/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="objective">
                    <xsl:variable name="current" select="." />
                <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="@objective"></xsl:value-of></td>                          
                        <xsl:for-each-group select="$allData" group-by="function/@function">
                             <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                             <td><xsl:value-of select="count($current[function/@function=current-grouping-key()])"/></td>
                        </xsl:for-each-group>
                </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tbody>
            </table>
    </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This produces the following output

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <th>Objective\Function</th>
               <th>X1</th>
               <th>X2</th>
               <th>X3</th>
               <th>X4</th>
               <th>X5</th>
               <th>X6</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Y1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>0</td>
               <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Y2</td>
               <td>0</td>
               <td>0</td>
               <td>0</td>
               <td>0</td>
               <td>0</td>
               <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Y3</td>
               <td>0</td>
               <td>0</td>
               <td>0</td>
               <td>0</td>
               <td>0</td>
               <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Y4</td>
               <td>0</td>
               <td>0</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>0</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Y5</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>0</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>0</td>
               <td>0</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```